# Is $\mathbb{A}_Q/\mathbb{Z}$ compact and connected?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}$be the the adéles of $\mathbb{Q}$ viewed as a group and consider $\mathbb{Z}$  as a subgroup in the natural manner.

Is $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ compact and connected?

I am not sure this is true, it is an exercise in Neukirch but maybe there is a misprint? It is easy to see that $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Q}$ is compact by weak approximation, but I don't think the same (?) should be true with $\mathbb{Z}$ instead. I think I can come up with counterexamples, for example, the elements $(1/2^i,1,1,\ldots,) \in \mathbb{Q}_2 \times \Pi_{p \text{ primes } \neq 2} \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}$ for $i>0$ shouldn't be approximated arbitrarily well by some integer $\mathbb{Z}!.$ Probably Neukirch intended to use $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{R},$ since in that case, the quotient by $\mathbb{Z}$ is compact and connected.

So, my question is, whether someone could confirm my suspicions that this is in fact, false. If it is true, I would be grateful for a proof of that as well.

Comment: You're right that it is a typo. It should be $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$... Your (counter-) example certainly succeeds.

Comment: @paulgarrett If you want to post this as an answer and get the answer accepted, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that this is a typo. It should be $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$. Your (counter-) example certainly succeeds.

Another way to see the compactness is to realize that the "solenoid" $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$ is the projective limit of circles $\mathbb R/n\mathbb Z$ where $n$ runs through integers ordered by divisibility. Since the projective limit is a closed subset of the corresponding product, by Tychonoff the projective limit is compact.

In a similar vein, $(\mathbb R\times \mathbb Q_p)/\mathbb Z[{1\over p}]$ is compact.